# How to Hide custom tab action bar

Tags: android, chrome-custom-tabs, android-customtabs

[image]Hi i am new to custom tabs i just want to hide action bar. Is there any way to do this any link, code and concept will be appreciated thanks in advance!

Here is the code!

```
CustomTabsIntent.Builder intentBuilder = new CustomTabsIntent.Builder();
    intentBuilder.setStartAnimations(this, R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
    intentBuilder.setExitAnimations(this, android.R.anim.slide_in_left,
        android.R.anim.slide_out_right);

    //Open the Custom Tab        
    intentBuilder.build().launchUrl(context, Uri.parse("https://developer.chrome.com/"));
```

Comment: You can set the theme for it having an <item name="windowActionBar">false</item>

Comment: @Umer Khan , have you been able to hide url bar in custom chrome tabs ?.

Answer (score -3):

You can hide Acton Bar in your Acitivity like this

```
getSupportActionBar().hide();
```

Hope this helps.